# React Native, Property 'setNativeProps' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I get the error when I try and call `setNativeProps`, any ideas?

```js
const inputElementRef = useRef(null);
      
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputElementRef.current !== null) {
    inputElementRef.current!.setNativeProps({
      style: { fontFamily: fonts.REGULAR },
    });
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you define the types possible for you `ref`, TS will not be able to figure it out.

```
 const inputElementRef = useRef(null);
```

The above statement indicates that `inputElementRef.current` will be always of type `null. But in reality,` null` is the initial value the ref hold but not the only value it can hold.

And since the if condition checks for non-null values, the only type left is `never` since the value of `inputElementRef.current` will never be not null according to the types defined by you.

Try to do this:

```
 const inputElementRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
```

Or replace `HTMLInputElement` with whatever type you think is suitable for the element.

Comment: Can read this : https://www.robinwieruch.de/typescript-react-useref/